# how to make a input field value in h1?

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span>
            <h1><input class="form-control" style="margin-top:50px; " type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']?>'/></h1>
            <input class="form-control " type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name'] ?>'/>
            <input class="form-control col-md-12 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name'] ?>'/>
            <input class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name'] ?>'/>
            <input class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name'] ?>'/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the text of first input box in h1 how to make it as a heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you show first input larger the other simple increase input box width and height

```html
<input style="width:100%; height:30px; font-size:30px" type='text' name='name'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use h1 tag with form elements you just have to increase it using height or width

```
<input style="width:60%; height:10%;  type='text' name='name'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<span>
<h1><input class="form-control" style="margin-top:50px; " type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']?>'/></h1>
<input class="form-control " type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']; ?>'/>
<input class="form-control col-md-12 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']; ?>'/>
<input class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']; ?>'/>
<input class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-6" type='text' name='company_name' value='<?php echo $row1['company_name']; ?>'/>
</span>
</div>
```

you should be getting errors because you didn't put the ; after $row1['company_name'];

Answer (score 0):

try with css..if you want to enclose it in

```
<style>
     h1 input{
            font-size:2em 
        }
</style>
```

or if without tag  then give any class name to input and apply the same css for that class

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
     h1 input
        {
            font-size:large 
        }
</style>
```

Also add semicolon ; after php script to avoid any errors