# how can I display input value in h1 in React JS

Tags: reactjs, input, display

I have one input which divides 2 number and gives value, so I want to display that value in h1 tag

```
 <input className='input' type="number" id="" placeholder='$' onChange={(evt) => {console.log(evt.target.value / coinId.price)}}/>
```

coinId.price is todays BTC price from API but it is not important at this point

here is code which gave me result in console log so any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting your point, can you please explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `value` attribute I think, and if you use React Hooks maybe you can do something like this :

````
import { useState } from "react";

const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

...


<input className="input" type="number" placeholder="$" onChange={(evt) => setInputValue(evt.target.value / coinId.price)} value={inputValue} />```
````

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods that I can think of is that, by using useState, set a state like

> `const (myAns,setMyAns) = useState(0)`

> `<input className='input' type="number" id="" placeholder='$' onChange={(evt) => {setMyAns(evt.target.value / coinId.price)}}/>`

> `<h1>{myAns}</h1>`

You can also use useEffect, so that whenever price of bitcoin is changed, you may get updated value.

Or

> `<h1><input className='input' type="number" id="" placeholder='$' onChange={(evt) => {setMyAns(evt.target.value / coinId.price)}} value={inputValue} /></h1>`

For furthur reference if case, [how to make a input field value in h1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690803/how-to-make-a-input-field-value-in-h1)

Comment: Please upvote if found helpful